# How to paint permanently on JComponent

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, graphics, shapes

I'm trying to create a paint application in Java.

- I have a "canvas" class which extends JComponent.
- I have an ArrayList of type Shape which holds all the shapes of the entire drawing.

Inside the paintComponent() method:

- Each loop everything gets cleared
- Every Shape inside the ArrayList gets painted with either g.draw() or g.fill()
- If I want to add a shape or draw a Shape, I add it to the ArrayList.

The problem is that after a considerably high amount of shapes inside the ArrayList, the execution of the paintComponent() method slows.

For example a custom brush.

- When dragging the brush over the canvas I have to add a new Shape of type "CustomBrush extends Shape" to the ArrayList
- So with just a single stroke I end up with hundreds of shapes in the ArrayList

The question is:

- How do I "pack" say 100 Shape objects into one, so that a single brush stroke becomes one single object in my ArrayList ?
- The ultimate goal is however to speed up the paintComponent() method so that it paints all the drawn Shapes faster.

Thank You!

Here's a sample code:

```
public class GraphicPanel extends JComponent{
  private ArrayList<Shape> shapeBuffer;

  public void paintComponent( Graphics gPlain ){
       Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gPlain;
       for( Shape s : shapeBuffer ){
        if( filled.next() ){
            g.fill( s );
        }
        else{
            g.draw( s );
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). It compares the two approaches 1) painting from a List and 2) painting to a BufferedImage and contains working examples of both approaches.

Comment: @camickr Thanks to Hovercraft Full Of Eels I could Implement both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paint the background to a BufferedImage, and then draw the BufferedImage to your GrahpicPanel within the `paintComponent(...)` method using `g.drawImage(...)`. You get the BufferedImage's Graphics context by calling `getGraphics()` or `createGraphics()` (for a Graphics2D object). Don't forget to dispose of the Graphics object obtained in this way (but never dispose of a Graphics object given to you by the JVM).

Also, don't forget to call the `super.paintComponent(g)` in your override!

For example:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MyPaint extends JComponent {
   private static final int PREF_W = 600;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private static final Stroke STROKE = new BasicStroke(4f);
   private static final Color[] COLORS = { Color.RED, Color.GREEN,
         Color.yellow, Color.orange, Color.blue, Color.cyan };
   private BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(PREF_W, PREF_H,
         BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
   private Rectangle rect = null;

   public MyPaint() {
      MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
      addMouseListener(myMouse);
      addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (img != null) {
         g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
      }
      if (rect != null) {
         g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         ((Graphics2D) g).draw(rect);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
      private Random random = new Random();
      private Point p;

      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         if (e.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            return;
         }
         p = e.getPoint();
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
         if (p != null) {
            Rectangle rect2 = createRect(e.getPoint());
            Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
            g2.setStroke(STROKE);
            Color c = COLORS[random.nextInt(COLORS.length)];
            g2.setColor(c);
            g2.fill(rect2);
            g2.setColor(c.darker());
            g2.draw(rect2);
            g2.dispose();
         }

         p = null;
         rect = null;
         repaint();
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
         rect = createRect(e.getPoint());
         repaint();
      }

      private Rectangle createRect(Point p2) {
         int x = Math.min(p.x, p2.x);
         int y = Math.min(p.y, p2.y);
         int width = Math.abs(p.x - p2.x);
         int height = Math.abs(p.y - p2.y);
         Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
         return rect2;
      }

   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      MyPaint mainPanel = new MyPaint();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyPaint");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Also, in mouseDragged() Why not just rect.setSize() ? Wastes less memory and less work for the garbage collector

Comment: @Fresco: that may very well be better. Go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Brushstroke and color are attributes of a shape.  You could define your own shape class like this.  That way, you're maintaining shapes in your List.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Shape;

public class MyShape {

    private int brushSize;

    private Color interiorColor;

    private Shape shape;

    public MyShape() {
        this.brushSize = 1;
        this.interiorColor = Color.blue;
    }

    public MyShape(int brushSize, Color interiorColor, Shape shape) {
        this.brushSize = brushSize;
        this.interiorColor = interiorColor;
        this.shape = shape;
    }

    public int getBrushSize() {
        return brushSize;
    }

    public void setBrushSize(int brushSize) {
        this.brushSize = brushSize;
    }

    public Color getInteriorColor() {
        return interiorColor;
    }

    public void setInteriorColor(Color interiorColor) {
        this.interiorColor = interiorColor;
    }

    public Shape getShape() {
        return shape;
    }

    public void setShape(Shape shape) {
        this.shape = shape;
    }

}
```

If I missed any attributes, feel free to add them to your shape class.

Comment: `"Brushstroke and color are attributes of a shape"` -- Maybe I'm misunderstanding your answer, but shouldn't this be "are **not** attributes of a shape"? Please clarify for me.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: When you draw or fill a shape, you can set the color and set the stroke before you draw or fill a shape.  That makes color and stroke attributes of the shape.

Comment: I agree theoretically, but I was reading it literally for the Shape *Interface* and its concrete classes which have no mechanism to make this so. So I see your point. 1+